# How to render multiple mp4 files on website

Tags: php, html, cloudinary

I am currently working a website (http://www.pdtv6.com) that contains list animated files and are paginated. The images resides on cloudinary and rendered once the user visits the website. The problem I am facing is the fact that images don't load once rather some will load while others don't load. With the little knowledge I have, I have ran out of ideas and I need help on how to make sure these images loads most importantly, it should be compatible with displaying on safari browser.

Here is the code that uploads to cloudinary:

```
\Cloudinary\Uploader::upload_large($path.$value['image_name'], [
    'folder' => '********',
    'public_id' => explode('.', $value['image_name'])[0],
    'use_filename' => TRUE,
    'resource_type' => "auto",
    'format' => 'mp4'
]);
```

Code that renders the cloudinary images is wrapped around foreach:

```
<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-6 col-6">
    <div class="row">
         <?php foreach ($current_batch as $key => $item):?>
             <div class="col-md-3 p-0 p-1">
                  <div class="card">
                       <a href="******">
                            <?php echo cl_video_tag($item['cloudinary_secure_url'], [
                                 "cloud_name" => ******,
                                 "width"=> 320, 
                                  "height"=> 180, 
                                  "crop"=>"fill",
                                   "autoplay" => true,
                                   "loop" => true,
                                   "fallback_content" => "Your browser does not support HTML5 video tags",
                                    "fetch_format" => "auto",
                                    ]) ?>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    <?php endforeach ?>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

I tried to access your site: http://www.pdtv6.com/ and all the images are loaded successfully and confirmed all of them are served through Cloudinary. 
Are you still running into issue?

Comment: Thanks. I have fixed the issue. I had to save images based on the browser's name. That way I was able to manipulate the format to be displayed for Safari and other browsers.